# the width of the p label doesn't work

Tags: css

The p part under ABOUT US. I have set width to its parent label div,which class is **'aboutus'**. but the p width doesn't work, even though I also set the width to the p label. it still doesn't work. why? and the p content is  out of range. How should I correct it?
    http://www.sunbucks-supply.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your width is perfectly fine (add for examlpe a `background: red`). The problem is your content: all whitespaces are somehow changed in an `&nbsp;` (non-breaking-space) which will (as the name suggest) don`t break the line into multiple lines to let the content fit.

Comment: Good find. I've been digging in the CSS, but totally overlooked this content issue.